# Visual artifacts in x2go XFCE4 sessions after upgrade from 20.04 to 21.04

Tags: xfce, 21.04, x2go

folks.

I've been using x2go XFCE4 sessions on a box for ages with no problems but after an upgrade to 21.04 (from 20.04) I'm now getting strange visual artifacts: black boxes around windows, ghosting, etc. (See screenshot below.)

If I login to the box regularly -- meaning not via x2go -- everything is fine.

Anybody have any ideas as to what might be happening?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you installed a custom theme and/or font pack? If required, have you updated your video drivers? Have you checked for x2go updates?

Comment: I wondered if I had an old theme loaded so I rm -rf'ed ~/.config/xfce4 and re-logged in and then set the theme anew. Same result. The x2go I'm running is the latest that came with Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: X2Go doesn't come with Ubuntu. Are you running Ubuntu, or some other derivative... like Mint or Pop or etc?

Comment: Is X2Go version 4.1.2.2?

Comment: On my installs x2goserver is in universe.

Comment: FWIW, the OS running x2goserver was running in a VM. I justu rebuilt the VM falling back to focal64 and things are working again. I guess the high-level take-away for anyone else finding this Q may be that the x2goserver on 21.04 may have some problems or perhaps its the combination of x2go client on 20.10 plus x2go on 21.04.

Comment: I wonder if it's a Wayland problem. Wayland is the default on Ubuntu 21.04, and optional on prior versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to XUbuntu 21.04.

To fix the issue I disabled "**Display compositing**" by going to
`Settings` > `Window Manager Tweaks` > `Compositor`.

I think it's related to Wayland as mentioned by @heynnema

Comment: Does the problem go away if you log out and log in with X.Org? You don't necessarily have to use Wayland, after all.

Comment: Interestingly enough, after a couple of weeks, I re-upgraded the VM to latest dev release and things are now working as expected without having to tweak the compositor setting. Which is good because within XFCE4 the above Settings > ... is not present.

Comment: FWIW, after another couple of weeks the problems did return and turning off compositing (as above) fixed the problem.